# Find fields with certain characters

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to SELECT fields with multiple dots ( . ) in their value.

Exactly, I'm trying to find fields with a subdomain as an entry in domain column, e.g.;

```
SELECT * FROM domains WHERE ( number of dots in domain value bigger than 1 ).
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
SELECT * FROM domains WHERE ( domain LIKE "%.%.%" ).
```

See the [MySQL Documentation for String functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/string-comparison-functions.html) for details.

Comment: lolz, time to get my coffee, I totally forgot that '%' is a wildcard :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
SELECT * FROM domains WHERE domain REGEXP '\\.+'
```

Assuming you want the dots placed near each other: `...`

Answer (score 0):

The [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) don't seem to have anything in that vein, so you may need the [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) operator.